# noblox.js and discord.js, currently using discord.js and got a intent error, v13

Tags: javascript, discord.js, roblox, replit

Was watching a tutorial on making a discord.js and noblox.js bot. error is something about intents not being a constructor or whatever. tutorial playlist isnt even helpful like the discord server. im just following the tutorial to set up a bot account and some slash commands with noblox.js (a roblox js API i guess or a wrapper idk)
code:

```
const { Client, Intents }  = require('discord.js')
const noblox = require('noblox.js')

const { Token } = require('./config.json')

// Create a new client instance
const intents = new Intents([
  'GUILDS',
  'GUILD_MEMBERS',
  'GUILD_MESSAGES'
])

const bot = new Client({ Intents : intents })


bot.login(Token)
bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`${bot.user.tag} has booted up.`)
})
```

error:

```
TypeError: Intents is not a constructor
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/ImpishDefiantClasses/index.js:7:17)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
```

IDE: Replit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, You should require intents:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");
const { Token } = require("./config.json")

const bot = new Client({
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
  Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
  Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
  Intents.FLAGS.MESSAGE_CREATE]
});
```

Then, the things we want to do when the bot is ready:

```js
bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`${bot.user.tag} is now online!`)
})
```

Also, Make sure you put `bot.login(Token)` **at the end of your code**.

At the end, If you want to receive messages, you need to listen to `messageCreate` event:

```js
client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.content.startsWith('!ping')) {
    message.reply('Pong!')
  }
});
```

So your code should look like this:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require("discord.js");

const bot = new Client({
  intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
  Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
  Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
  Intents.FLAGS.MESSAGE_CREATE]
});

bot.on('ready', () => {
  console.log(`${bot.user.tag} is now online!`)
})

client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;
  if (message.content.startsWith('!ping')) {
    message.reply('Pong!')
  }
});

bot.login(Token);
```

[More info](https://v13.discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#privileged-intents) on intents.

Comment: Thank you, I was going to be more stupid by installing more versions of discord v13 because that's what the dev told me.